# No matter what I do I keep getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask

No matter what I do I keep getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'. I think it has to do with my variable ajax_data, so I made some attempts to try to fix it. Here are some attempts I have made to solve this error:

```
ajax_data = json.load(request.data.read().decode('utf-8')) 
ajax_data = json.loads(request.data.read().decode('utf-8'))
ajax_data = json.loads(request.data.read())
ajax_data = json.load(request.data.read())
ajax_data = json.load(request.data.decode())
ajax_data = json.loads(request.data.decode())
```

Here is my code:

```
@portfolio_app.route('/postContactForm', methods=['POST'])
def postContactForm():
    #Gets the data sent from frontend  
    ajax_data = json.load(request.data.decode()) 
    print(ajax_data)

    # Connect to DB
    db = connectToDB()

    #Choose collection name
    contact_data = db.contact_data
    print(contact_data)

    #Inserts data into database
    contact_data.insert_one(ajax_data)

    #Returns data to ajax
    return jsonify({'Success it worked'})
```

Comment: Please include the full error traceback

Comment: Could you print out `type(request.data)`?

Answer (score 1):

You should change this:

```
request.data.read()
```

into this:

```
request.data
```

`request.data` is already a string, there's no point "reading" it.

---

trying to answer the question in the comments. instead of `ajax_data = json.load(request.data)` you should use something like this:

```
try :
    ajax_data = json.loads(request.data)  # notice: loadS here
except :
    print( 'Invalid JSON data', request.data )
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your response. I just tried it (  ajax_data = json.load(request.data)) and I got  AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read' still

Comment: @kvothe you should have tried `loadS` with "S" on the end. (lowercase 's')

Comment: Ya I tired that too and got TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable

Comment: @kvothe well, print is out (`print request.data`) and see if it's JSON, then?

Comment: I am sorry I am very new to programming could you please explain in more detail what you are asking me to do. Once again thank you for your help!!!!

Comment: @kvothe see the edited answer

Comment: I got this error raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable.

Comment: request.get_json() should be used instead